# How to read data from CosmosDb when i only have the partitionkey but not the id of the document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When trying to read from CosmosDb i can select a document via:

- Id Query
- Id + PartitionKey Query

but how do i select data from CosmosDb when i only have the PartitionKey?

```csharp
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
        
public class CosmosDbService : ICosmosDbService
{
    private Container _container;
    
    public CosmosDbService(
            CosmosClient cosmosDbClient,
            string databaseName,
            string containerName)
    {
        _container = cosmosDbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
    }
    
    public async Task<Error> GetItemAsync(string partitionKey)
    {
        // selection only via partitionKey - does not work
        var response = await _container.ReadItemAsync<Error>(partitionKey, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
        return response.Resource;

        // below one works as i am passing the Id (internally generated by CosmosDB)
        var id = "2e4e5727-86ff-4c67-84a6-184b4716d744";
        var response = await _container.ReadItemAsync<Error>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
        return response.Resource;
    }
}
```

Question:
Are there any other methods in CosmosDB client which can return the document using the PartitionKey ONLY without the need of Id which I don't know ?

Comment: Are you passing `/customerId` as input to `GetItemAsync` method or the actual value of the customer id. You would need to pass the actual value instead of the partition key attribute name.

Comment: Yes I am passing CustomerId value

Comment: So when you pass `partitionKey` as `2e4e5727-86ff-4c67-84a6-184b4716d744`, you don't get any data back. Is that correct?

Comment: I am trying to get the record  using "CustomerId"  but its not returning data unless I pass both "Id-->generated internally by csomosDB" and CustomerId which is the partitionkey

Comment: To read a single item, you need to pass both document id and the partition key value.

Comment: FYI there are *reads* and *queries*. Your code has *reads*, which require both an `id` and the partition key's value (as noted in another comment). *Queries* don't require any particular field (and you can decide whether to provide a partition key value, or perform a cross-partition query). Try doing a *query* (with something like `select * from...`), just specifying partition key value. That will likely get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting documents you could try to use QueryDefinition + QueryAsync:

```csharp
var query = new QueryDefinition("select top 1 * from c");
var partitionKey = "PARTITIONKEY";
var resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<ModelObject>(query, null, new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) });
var result = new List<ModelObject>();

while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
{
    var item = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync(ct /* CancellationToken */).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var itemList = item.ToList();
    result.AddRange(itemList);
}
```

Instead of a top 1 select you could also do a select * (for example)

Comment: Thanks Stephan.  couple of questions 1. var partitionKey = "ID OF PARTITION";, you mean value of the Partitionkey right say for example  if i want to get the record where  customerId =C0001, i should be assigning "C0001" :in the partitionkey variable?   what will be return value is it result([0]  .  2) what is "ct" passed to the ReadNextAsync?

Comment: @novice8989 yes the partitionkey value. the result will be list of all the objects that match the query. ct is a CancellationToken. if you call this without having a CancellationToken just use CancellationToken.None. The problem with your code in question is that you select from a partition with value "xyz" and want to retrieve the document with id value "xyz".